# Alpha and Beta of a Transistor

Tags: transistors, bjt

So the parameter beta for a Common Emitter Amplifier is called the **Current Gain** and is defined as

\$\beta =\dfrac{I_\mathrm{collector}}{I_\mathrm{base}}\$

\$\alpha =\dfrac{I_\mathrm {collector}}{I_\mathrm{emitter}}\$

What is this \$\alpha\$ called and what is its significance?

Like for example \$\beta\$ can be treated as the amount by which a signal is getting modified.

Comment: On Mathjax: Because engineering often involves how much something costs. Also, Mathjax wasn't added to the site until a few hundred questions had already been asked and answered.

Comment: Note: You can still do display equations with `$$`.

Comment: @ThePhoton So? How does that relate?

Comment: If they had added Mathjax using just `$` as a delimiter, it would have broken existing questions that talked about costs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\$\beta\$ is a **ratio** between the collector and base currents whereas \$\alpha\$ is also a ratio but between the collector and emitter currents. There is no special name for \$\alpha\$ and \$\beta\$ as they are both unit-less.

However, you may call \$\alpha\$ as the **common-base gain** and \$\beta\$ as the **common-emitter gain**.

Either way, you will usually see \$\beta\$ in the spec sheets of BJT chips.

\$\alpha\$ is always less that 1.0 because of [carrier generation and recombination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier_generation_and_recombination) going through the base region of the transistor, thus, the base and collector current are always less than the emitter current.

There is a relationship between \$\alpha\$ and \$\beta\$...

\$\displaystyle \beta= \frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}\$

(Also, I asked a question about [why Mathjax is different on the EE.SE](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6427/why-does-our-inline-syntax-for-mathjax-different-from-say-the-math-se) than other websites.)

Comment: No, \$\alpha\$ is always less than 1 because collector current is always less than emitter current -- the difference is the base current. This is a simple application of [Kirchhoff's current law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff's_current_law_(KCL)) -- the sum of all three currents must be 0.

Comment: @DaveTweed We were taught this using a CB pnp transistor that a fraction of the  holes from the emitter go to the collector. This fraction is called \$\alpha\$. The rest go through the base. Is that correct?

Comment: @harshit54: Yes, that's correct. It's one measure of the "efficiency" of the transistor.

Comment: @harshit54 In reply to what you asked me: Yes there exists a common-collector characteristic. I was about to type it out but user G36 answered that in their answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we have:

1 - "beta"  \$\beta = \frac{I_C}{I_B}\$ for **common-emitter** current gain.

2 - "alpha" \$\alpha = \frac{I_C}{I_E} =\frac{I_C}{I_B +I_C}= \frac{\beta \cdot I_B}{I_B +\beta \cdot I_B}=  \frac{\beta}{\beta + 1}\$ for **common-base** current gain.

3 - "gamma" \$\gamma = \frac{I_E}{I_B} = \frac{I_B + I_C}{I_B} = \frac{I_B +\beta \cdot I_B}{I_B} =\beta + 1 = \frac{1}{1-\alpha} \$ for **common-collector** current gain.