# What does this ɣ constant relate to in the carrier motion of BJT

Tags: semiconductors, charge, pnp

What does the constant  ***ɣ*** represent in the following carrier motion of an PNP transistor?

[image]

So I see three components for the base current.

1) According to the illustration I can see that some of the majority carriers in the base which are electrons recombine with some of the holes rushing into the base from the emitter. To replenish this loss of electrons due to recombination, an electron current flows into the base from the base terminal.

2) Thermally generated holes in the base and electrons in the collector cross the collector-base junction contributes to the collector current. The flow of these also forms part of the base current. The reverse saturation current is the flow of holes only I guess.

3) There are also electrons flowing from the base into the emitter. I never saw this before.

What does (1-***ɣ***) indicate? What does this contribute to? Is this a usually neglected component?

Comment: Can you share where you found the diagram?

Comment: Yes somewhere in google books wait a minute

Comment: @ThePhoton page 82 here https://books.google.dk/books?id=8686A5TLsjAC&pg=PA556&lpg=PA556&dq=Electronics+analog+and+digital+nagrath&source=bl&ots=oqS8GxsO40&sig=ACfU3U3p-r4ALOT-dUO6oyGDUS6yNKCXRA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjS4dWe0JHiAhUQtYsKHQW5ACcQ6AEwHHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false but Im not able to send exact page just write recombination in search and click on page 82

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/414911/alpha-and-beta-of-a-transistor/414917#414917

Comment: @G36 That's a different meaning than the OP needs. I will have to go look it up, but my intuition says its the ratio of the total mobile charges divided into the total mobile majority charges. That will usually be very close to 1.

Comment: @jonk, If so, gamma = emitter injection efficiency https://www.quora.com/What-is-emitter-injection-efficiency-in-a-BJT

Comment: @G36 That looks like you've nailed it, to me!